# Extracting n-grams from docoument and counting their frequencies

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

I want to extract n-grams from a file and then count the frequency of them. My problem is that their is no real output, it says only:

```
<generator object ngrams at 0x7fad3d528580>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What does that mean? How can I get a "real" output (n-grams and their frequency). Can you help me to solve my problem?

```
import nltk, re, string, collections
from nltk.util import ngrams
with open("corpus.txt", "r", encoding='latin-1') as file:
 text = file.read()
 text = text[0:100]

tokenized = text.split()
esBigrams = ngrams(tokenized, 2)
esBigramFreq = collections.Counter(esBigrams)
esBigramFreq.most_common(10)
print(esBigrams)
```

Comment: Changet the last line to `print(list(esBigrams))`. You can learn the difference between a list and a generator here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions basically, a generator is like a list but it only calculates the next object when you iterate over it instead of your code having to wait until all the elements are calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Your current program is returning a generator object, which behaves like an iterator. That is, it is designed to be iterated through with a `for` loop or the like to generate individual values. Printing them out usually just returns their default, vague Python representation.

[From the documentation:](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

> Generator functions allow you to declare a function that behaves like an iterator, i.e. it can be used in a for loop.

To take advantage of its values, you could iterate through the generator object yourself with a `for` loop, and `print` out each item.

But the better option, as said in [Boris's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3064538/boris) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66955562/extracting-n-grams-from-docoument-and-counting-their-frequencies#comment118352307_66955562), is simply passing the generator object to the `list()` constructor, which will automatically iterate through it and return a list, which is more useful and printable.